# Is using the PayPal IPN as a API trigger a good implementation?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

As recommended by PayPal I am using a combination of the PayPal API and the IPN to create a 'Adaptive Payments' flow.

When my IPN listener receives a new notification from PayPal I have two options (after security checks):

1) Use the received data to make direct actions in my website (for example set a preapproval as approved)

or instead a more secure and clean way (I think):

2) Detect the transaction type variable (or other identifier) and request more details from PayPal accordingly.

For example if the 'transaction_type' is 'Adaptive Payment Preapproval'  then I will use the received  'preapproval_key' to request the preapproval details using the PreapprovalDetails API call and then use the received data of that call to set the preapproval as approved.

Is this (option 2) the better way to go?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In general there is probably enough information in the IPN for you to act on, but IPNs are pretty confusing what with all the optional fields and the way that there is no payment_status or txn_id on subscribe events, and no subscription information on payment events, so marrying them up can be interesting. You may well find it easier to understand if you go ahead and get the relevant information from them for each IPN via their API as you suggest.